# Ios Adobe Creative Sdk Customization

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have successfully integrated Adobe Creative SDK (Image Editor) in my iOS application.And now I wanted to add my own features to this editor such as i want to add my own stickers into the sticker header.I have explored but found nothing.My code is

```
@IBAction func btnBrowseAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let editorController = AdobeUXImageEditorViewController (image:  UIImage (named: "3_1_Greeting_Screen_Landscap_1.jpg")!)
    let editorCustomzation =        AdobeImageEditorCustomization.setToolOrder([_kAFStickers(),_kAFFrames() as Any])

    self.present(editorController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    editorController.delegate = self
}

func photoEditor(_ editor: AdobeUXImageEditorViewController,  finishedWith image: UIImage?) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    imageVieww.image = image
}

func photoEditorCanceled(_ editor: AdobeUXImageEditorViewController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Is there any way to do this? please suggest me.